# Magento 2 table not found after Migration

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

Migrated data from Magento 1.9.3.8 using the migration tool
Attempt to access or index Customers

**Expected result:** (*)
re-index customers or load customer tab

**Actual result:** (*)

> **Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'larpwarr_SSwordsMagento2.mg2_' doesn't exist, the query was: DESCRIBE
>   mg2_**

Prior to the migration, this was looking into the `**customer_grid**` table correctly, '**mg2_customer_grid**' however since the migration it seems to have dropped out the '**customer_grid**' part and is now looking for a non-existent table.

Any ideas why, or where this value is stored/pulled from so I can look into altering it back to what it should be?